# Centering with an image and h2 inside a div

Tags: html, css, centering

I just can't figure this out. Everyone has to start somewhere, I am just starting to learn CSS so bear with me. Hope you all understand.

So currently this is what is being displayed in the browser

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gktJpXC.png]

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="section-2">

                <ul class="big-features">

                    <li>

                        <img src="images/accept.png">
                        <h2>Easily Accept Credit</br>Cards</h2>

                    </li>
                    <li>

                        <img src="images/location.png">
                        <h2>Multiple Location</br>Inventory</h2>

                    </li>
                    <li>

                        <img src="images/faster.png">
                        <h2>Make Faster</br>Transactions</h2>

                    </li>
                    <li>

                        <img src="images/inventory.png">
                        <h2>Powerful Inventory</br>Management</h2>

                    </li>

                </ul>

        </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.section-2
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f6f8f8;
    text-align: center;
}
.big-features ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;

}
.big-features ul li
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.3em; 
    padding: 0;
}
.big-features img
{
    width: 80px;
    padding: 15px 0px 6px 0px;
}
.big-features h2
{
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Here is what I want it to look like.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHnKm.jpg]

Comment: you must display the li as inline or inline-block.

Answer (score 2):

Rules like `.big-features ul` won't work here because this tries to select a `<ul>` element that's a descendant of an element with the class `.big-features`. To select that element use either `.big-features` or `ul.big-features`. A space in a selector means look for a descendant.

The easiest solution would be to just remove the `ul` from most of your rules:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/80w4js6d/)**

Answer (score 1):

change your CSS to this:

```
.section-2
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f6f8f8;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.big-features 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;

}
ul.big-features li
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 0.7em; 
    padding: 0;
}
ul.big-features img
{
    width: 80px;
    padding: 15px 0px 6px 0px;
}
.big-features h2
{
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: to whoever voted this down I'd like an explanation on why because I can't see any error at all. And btw, wrote it out of my head, but tested in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/51vpdab3/ and it works better than any of the solutions provided (check alignment of elements).

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add:

```
li{
    float:left;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z96xhqsL/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is with this selector `.big-features ul li`. It says select `li` elements that are descendants of a `ul` element that is ***a descendant of an element with a class of `big-features`***.

What you want is `ul.big-features li` which selects `li` elements that descend from a `ul` with a class of `big-features`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is move the `display:inline` to the `li` instead of the `ul` tag.

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to apply `display:inline-block` and `list-style:none`
  to your `li` and not the ul.
- Second in your css `.big-features ul` means, it searches for `ul`
  with a `parent` having class `big-features`(which is not present in
  your html), the correct way would be `ul.big-features` which means ul
  tag having class big-features

So your correct CSS should be

```
ul.big-features
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;


}
ul.big-features li
{

    margin-right: 1.3em; 
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/00kaqz9c/